# How can a uniform prior make the posterior mean different from the MLE?

Tags: prior, mode, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior

I read the following in [Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262018020):

[image]

How can a uniform prior move the posterior mean? Isn't a uniform distribution supposed to not bias the result? Are there any other examples where this happens?

**Note:** In my original question I had misread the paragraph. I fixed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uniform prior does not move the mode.  The mode of the posterior is equal to the mle in this case.  The comparison is made between the posterior expectation, or mean value, and the mle.

From a pragmatic perspective, the argument is a bit silly, as the two values differ by an order of $\frac {2}{N_1+N_0 } $ anyway.  So the only time they are different is when you have a small sample size - in which case niether falls outside the "region of uncertainty" associated with the other.

Comment: Thanks - you are right. I corrected the question. when you said *"the posterior is equal to the MLE **in this case**"* , are there any distributions where the posterior mode is different from the MLE when using a uniform prior?

Comment: user023472 - posterior $\propto$ likelihood $\times$ prior. If prior is uniform, posterior $\propto$ likelihood. In that case, they necessarily share a mode. (For them not to, the previous argument has to break down somewhere...)

Comment: This is due to the lack of invariance of the uniform prior.  For example, The posterior mode for the odds $\gamma=\frac {\theta}{1-\theta} $ is not equal to the mle of the odds, under a uniform prior for $\theta $